# Fast select with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Please can anyone help me, i want to create a **fast select** with **Ionic**

Like this image :

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: Yes, I am developing an application with Ionic,i try to create it with simple select but i want to create a professional View, but I'm stuck in this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**angucomplete-alt**](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt). To see a demo [go here](https://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt).

```
bower install angucomplete-alt --save
```

---

---

[Here](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt/pull/312) is step-by-step how to use **multiselect**:

**1.** set angucomplete dependency from MartinNuc repo:

bower.json/package.json:

```
dependencies: {
   "angucomplete": "MartinNuc/angucomplete-alt#multiselect",
  ...
}
```

**2.** see updated readme for multiselect at the end of [this table](https://github.com/MartinNuc/angucomplete-alt/tree/multiselect#description-of-attributes)

**3.** use directive like this:

`<div angucomplete-alt
      pause="400"
      remote-url="/api/endpoint?query="
      selected-object="vm.addSelectedItemFromRemoteAutocomplete"
      search-fields="name"
      title-field="name"
      clear-selected="true"
      input-class="form-control form-control-small"
      match-class="highlight"
      multi-select="true"
      excluded-items="vm.selectedItems"
      exclude-on-select="true"
      exclusion-comparer-field="id">`

Pay attention to the last 4 attributes:

- `multi-select` - causes that angucomplete select will remain opened after clicking on an item
- `excluded-items` - this is used to hide items that are already selected during load phase
- `exclude-on-select` - when clicking on an item it will hide it immediately after clicking on them
- `exclusion-comparer-field` - this is handy when you load data from database and want to compare excluded items by some specific field and not just JS reference. We use `id`.

**4.** add `vm.addSelectedItemFromRemoteAutocomplete` function to your
    controller. This will add actually selected item to your property.

```
function addSelectedItemFromRemoteAutocomplete(item) {
      if (item && item.originalObject) {
         vm.selectedItems.push(item);
      }
    }
```

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thank you very much for your efforts.